# Naming of filenames, classes and protocols?

Tags: swift

When I use protocols with structural patterns such as MVP, or VIPER I usually add protocol and class conforming to the protocol in the same file.

For example, in MVP for the `View` component:

```
file: ListViewController.swift
protocol ListView {}
class ListViewController: ListView {}
```

and for the `Presenter` component:

```
file: ListPresenter.swift
protocol ListPresenter {}
class MainListPresenter : ListPresenter {}
```

1) is adding protocols and classes (when there is only one class conforming to it) in the same file, a good practice?

2) is ok to name the file containing the view controller with its name?

3) can I name the presenter file with the protocol name or do I lack of consistency?

How would you name filenames and classes in this example?

thanks

Comment: Viper related: https://medium.com/@Pr0Ger/why-viper-is-a-bad-choice-for-your-next-application-725f4e16fbee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) is adding protocols and classes (when there is only one class conforming to it) in the same file, a good practice?

If there's only one class conforming to a protocol, I would strongly argue that you're misusing protocols. If your pattern encourages this, then I would strongly question the value of the pattern.

But putting them in the same file is fine. Placing closely related types in a single file is good.

> 2) is ok to name the file containing the view controller with its name?

Sure.

> 3) can I name the presenter file with the protocol name or do I lack of consistency?

Sure...but again, if you have a protocol that has exactly one implementation, then something is likely wrong, and you should be digging into improving that rather than filenames.

Comment: I was forced to use VIPER on one project and I have to agree strongly with this opinion. This is done to easily enable mocking of the individual layers but in my opinion the architecture would be better without mocking and using UI tests instead of unit tests. It creates an enormous number of layers, each with its own protocol which are only delegating to each other.

Comment: Even the issue of unit tests can often be greatly improved by abstraction rather than mocking. https://youtu.be/DXwJg0QTlZE

Comment: @RobNapier Indeed the reason why I only have one class conforming to the protocol is that I'm using protocols to decouple the classes and allow unit test mocking. However my question was more about the naming of filename and classes... do you agree with the snippet in the question?

Comment: The snippet is fine; the only reason it's becoming a problem is that you're likely over-using protocols. Achieving good testability typically does not require tons of mocks and protocols. When you simplify the architecture, the concerns you have over which file to put things in will often disappear.